# What is the difference between Apache mod_expires and mod_cache?

Tags: apache2

In simple terms, what is the main difference between `mod_expires` and `mod_cache`?

Comment: I've voted to re-open this question as it is about Apache, which is a package in Ubuntu's official repositories. AFAIK we allow questions about official Ubuntu software/packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't the names tell it all? The official [caching document](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html) points to ...

[**mod-cache**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html)

> mod_cache is an RFC 2616 compliant HTTP content cache that can be used to cache content.

- So it is the module for setting up caching.

[**mod-expire**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html)

> is responsible for setting of the "Expires" HTTP header and "max-age" directive of Cache-Control HTTP header in server responses.

- So it sets the maximum age and when caching expires.

Comment: I thought that once you activate mod_expire --- You have caching. I seem to have been wrong and mod_expire needs caching to be activated independently to work (and as you explained, it's via enabling mod_cache).

Comment: @Benia None of those 2 modules rely on each other to work. In simpler terms, `mod-cache` is for server-side caching while `mod-expires` is for leveraging browser caching (It adds headers to responses which tell the browser that a resource will be the same for a certain amount of time, so the browser won't request it again until that time passes).

Comment: Your comment helped me to figure out the difference even more, Deep thank you Dan!